# Python using super to override attributes, unexpected argument error when passing arguments

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a piece class for a chess program which I want other pieces to inherit from:

```
class Piece:
    def __init__(self, player, diag, straight, opponent, marker, unicode):

        self.player = player
        self.diag = diag
        self.straight = straight
        self.opponent = opponent
        self.marker = marker
        self.unicode = unicode
```

and for example, a king class that must set attributes that are specific to itself but part of the base class attributes:

```
from Piece import Piece

class King(Piece):

    def __init__(self, player, opposition, unicode):
        super.__init__(player,False, False, opposition,"K", unicode)
        self.has_moved = False
        self.casle_king = True
        self.castle_queen = True
```

My problem is that when I pass these into the super function, they throw an unexpected argument error even though I have defined them in the piece.

What is the correct way for the King to inherit from Piece but also set particular attributes that they share differently?

Comment: `super` should be `super()`.

Comment: but then how do I change the particular boolean values like Piece.straight as False?

Comment: Just change `super` to `super()` and it'll work.

Comment: Oh I see I thought you meant just leave it to super without passing in arguments.

Comment: @entercaspa nope, Aran-Fey means _exactly_ what he wrote: you must call `super`  - IOW you want      `super().__init__(player,False, False, opposition,"K", unicode)`

Comment: NB : assuming Python3 of course. In Python2, you want  `super(King, self).__init__(player,False, False, opposition,"K", unicode)`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the parentheses on super:

```
super().__init__(player,False, False, opposition,"K", unicode)
```

Or:

```
Piece.__init__(self, player,False, False, opposition,"K", unicode)
```